# How can I see which files have changes with Webstorm/GIT/OSX?

Tags: macos, git, webstorm

I have just started using Webstorm and OSX for my development with GIT. When I was using Windows I could use tortoise git and I would see little icons in Visual Studio and on the file system showing me the status of files such as /changed/same/ignored.

What I really want instead of the command line is to be able to see little status symbols on my files in 'finder'

Answer (score 2):

WebStorm has VCS integration, it shows what files were changes, added or deleted in the Project view highlighting their names with different colors.
You could also see the changelists, use visual diff tool and more. I suggest watching this [video](http://youtu.be/nLwseyjzmdI) on VCS integration in WebStorm and PhpStorm.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider a shell like [Prezto](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto), illustrated in "[ZSH/PREZTO GIT DIRTY PROMPT INFO](http://omarriott.com/aux/zsh-prezto-git-dirty-info/)".
Using [this prompt setup](https://github.com/rktjmp/prezto/blob/soup/modules/prompt/functions/prompt_soup_setup), you can add information as to the current status of your repo:

> Things like how long since the last commit, the current branch, whether I've added or modified files.
>   I also like to have two symbols, a green tick and a red lightning bolt visible as a general "you should commit your work" flag.

[image: http://omarriott.com/images/stream/2013-08-05-zsh-git-info/prompt-2.png]

Comment: Hi I want to see little icons on my files in finder? is this possible?

Comment: @Exitos Not that I know of (but I am not a Mac specialist). After that, this is more for GUI to propose a nice status visualization (like Tower http://www.git-tower.com/), or alternative file browser like Path Finder (http://lifehacker.com/5824343/the-best-alternative-file-browser-for-mac). But since you mentioned "command line", I though I could mention that option in my answer.